# EF Core: Add element to Collection without retrieving full object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

I have some code looking like this:

Controller:

```
foreach (Guid id in someModel.Ids)
{
    var someSlowToFetchEntity = await dbContext.SlowClass.FindAsync(id);
    someOtherEntity.AddSlowEntity(someSlowToFetchEntity)
}
```

Model someOtherEntity:

```
private ObservableCollection<SlowClass> _SlowEntity = new();
public ObservableCollection<SlowClass> SlowEntity
{
    get
    {
        return __lazyLoader.Load(this, ref _SlowEntity);
    }
    set
    {
        _SlowEntity = value;
    }
}

public SlowClass AddSlowEntity(SlowClass slowClass)
{
    SlowEntity.Add(slowClass);
    return slowClass;
}
```

SlowClass:

```
namespace SomeDataModel {
    public class SlowClass : Entity {

        public static SlowClass Create(IEntityCreationContext ecc) {
            return new SlowClass(ecc);
        }

        private string _Name;
        public string Name {
            get {
                return _Name;
            }
            set {
                if (_Name != value) {
                    NotifyPropertyChanging();
                    _Name = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }  
        
        // This is potentailly huge(up to 50MB allowed)
        private byte[] _Content;
        public byte[] Content
        {
            get {
                return _Content;
            }
            set {
                if (_Content != value) {
                    NotifyPropertyChanging();
                    _Content = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        public override void LoadDefaults(DbContext dbc) {
            base.LoadDefaults(dbc);
        }
    }


    class _SlowClassConfiguration : _EntityWithMetaDataConfiguration, IEntityTypeConfiguration<Attachment> {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<SlowClass> builder) {
            base.Configure<SlowClass>(builder);

            builder.Property(x => x.Name);
            builder.Property(x => x.Content);
        }
    }

}
```

DBSets:

```
        public DbSet<SomeOtherEntity> SomeOtherEntity { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SlowClass> SlowClass { get; set; }
```

The problem is finding and retrieving the slow entity takes roughly 30s (because it's a big entity, a few MBs big).
EF Core in the end only needs to save the id of the slow entity, is there any way, to save the id directly without fetching the slowEntity first?

Comment: Can you show your SlowEntity  and Slow class, the relations part pls? I don't understand what are you trying to reach

Comment: @Serge I corrected the naming, I guess that is what confused you, I'm meanwhile adding my SlowClass

Comment: Thanks, I still can't understand the relations. You use syntax I never seen before.  Can you post list of  dbsets like this   public virtual DbSet<Slow> Slow { get; set; } and so on

Comment: Done, does that help? Consistently renaming something for a demo is hard, fixed that again. See Controller again :)

Answer (score 0):

See if this is helpful: [Efficient Updating - EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/efficient-updating)

Here, it's talking about updating a large number of records, but the same advice may apply to your case:

> Unfortunately, EF doesn't currently provide APIs for performing bulk
> updates. Until these are introduced, you can use raw SQL to perform
> the operation where performance is sensitive:
>
> `context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("UPDATE [Employees] SET [Salary] = [Salary] + 1000");`

So, when EF Core doesn't have an efficient solution, you can fall back on SQL.

Comment: That sounds like it could help in my case, thank you very much, will mark your answer in a few days. If no one else comes in :)